# When i`m using the induction, I can`t notice some part in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, induction

For example let $X:= [0,+\infty]$ with the extended standard topology.
Let $A_i, A_j$ are measurable subsets such that $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$.

Then I can get that

(1)Equation $\mu(S)=\mu(S\cap A_i\cup A_j)-\mu(S\backslash(A_i\cup A_j)$ for any $S$ And

(2)$A_i\cup A_j$ is measurable set.

First, $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N} A_{i} = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N-1} A_{i}\cup A_N$ implise induction.

So, I conclude that
for all of $N\in \mathbb{N}$, Equation (1) holds. i.e.

$\mu(S)=$ $\mu(S\cap$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N} A_{i})$$+\mu(S\backslash\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N}A_{i}).$
Here, I happend to have a question.

When I wanted to claim the following $\mu(S)=$ $\mu(S\cap$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i})$$+\mu(S\backslash\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i})$,

[1]. Because for all of $N\in \mathbb{N}$, Equation (1) holds, can I put $\infty$ on $N$ ?or

[2]. Because I apply $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ both sides to  $\mu(S)=$ $\mu(S\cap$$\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N} A_{i})$$+\mu(S\backslash\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{N}A_{i}), $can I put $\infty$ on $N$?

In the latter case, To put "$lim$" in $\mu$, i think that there are more something condition. (for example continuous.)

Which is right?

And second question, For example In Euclidean space.
$A, B$ are open sets. Then $A \cap B$ is also open. I think that from $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{N}A_{i} = \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{N-1}A_{i}\cap A_N$ and induction then

for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$, $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{N}A_{i}$ is open.

If above [1] logic was right, i could put $\infty$ in $N$ and  $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}$ is open. but I already knew, it`s not correct. because for $A_i = (0-\frac{1}{i+1},1+\frac{1}{i+1})$,

$\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}$ is closed.

Where did i misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2):

$\infty$ is not a positive integer. If a property  holds for each $n$ you cannot put $n=\infty$ in it. In both cases you have to take limits.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could i ask to you one more? limit is able to put in $\mu$?

Comment: @G.rookie  A basic property of any measure is continuity from below: if $E_n$ increases to $E$ then $\mu (E_n) \to \mu(E)$. However continuity from above is not true unless the measure is  a finite measure. If $\mu (S)<\infty$ the you can take limit as $N \to \infty$ to get (2).

Comment: Thanks to Kavi Rama Murthy.